# Print all characters between two given letters

Tags: javascript, java

I want to just print all characters in alphabetical order between two given character inputs.

In Java, I can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (char i = 'A'; i <= 'D'; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

This prints `A B C D`.

Now I want to do the same operation in JavaScript:

```
for(var i='A'; i<='D'; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Here the output is `A undefined`.

What is the correct way to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Please tag on relevant tags ,thankyou.

Comment: Please clarify your question just a bit. You state: _between two given character inputs_ - yet your example (and my answer follows this example) output is inclusive.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, anything is fine. The problem is, I was not able to get the characters between them

Comment: What isnt fine is the fact that you still didn't edit the tags of your question. It still says java there, although it was suggested to you 30 minutes ago to fix that.

Comment: IMO Java tag is appropriate as it is a conversion between Java and JavaScript code.

Comment: Well, first you have to define your alphabet. Is it uppercase [ISO Basic Latin Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_basic_Latin_alphabet)? A literal string would make the clearest, both in the question and the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
for(var i='A'.charCodeAt(); i<='D'.charCodeAt(); i++) {
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(i));
}
```

Have to convert to and from char codes in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var value = 10; //adjustment to convert number to alphabet
for(var i=0; i<=3; i++){
document.write((value + i).toString(36).toUpperCase());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [ASCII Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), you can loop through all the numerical valeus of the letters you want and convert them to their corresponding letter using `String.fromCharCode`.

Example:

```js
for(let i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
  console.log(String.fromCharCode(i));
}
```

Comment: He wants to print characters ,he doesn't knows the keycode

Comment: That's why I linked Wikipedia's article on ASCII.

Comment: But that's not how it works,I am not downvoting but that's not the proper answer,it works doesn't always mean its right :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const A = 65;
const Z =91
for(var i=A; i<=Z; i++) {
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(i));
}
```

Comment: He wants to print characters ,he doesn't knows the keycode

Answer (score 0):

The letter **A** in the ASCII table is represented by 65 and **B** with 66 and so on.

```
const A = 65;
const Z = 91;
for(var i=A; i<=Z; i++) {
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(i));
}
```

Comment: ASCII not relevant to either Java or JavaScript. They, like many modern environments, use Unicode.